# Meaning of "Natural 1x1" in an image tag

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking at an img tag, using Chrome Dev Tools, that has a src attribute for a 1x1 image:

[image]

The image is actually 199 x 362 on the page.  What is this "Natural 1x1" specification? I notice that there are several other images on the page that have this exact 1x1 src, but the images are different.

Does anyone know what's being done here?

I'd like to download the image, but all I get is the same 1x1 for all  the img tags.

Thanks

Comment: This is a trick to prevent downloading images from right-click.  They overlay an element with a transparent pixel over the real image so if you right click you get the 1px element.  These are not the droids you are looking for.  Search for an image element nearby in the dom inspector to get your real image.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's the original size of the image (download it and you'll see). 199x362 is its size on the page achieved by CSS stretching (defining width and/or height).

You're probably looking at a transparent GIF pixel converted into a rectangle by stretching that's put on top of something else.

So this:

```
x
```

becomes this (or whatever the size):

```
\   /
 \ /
  X
 / \
/   \
```

Comment: This is what it is supposed to be. There seems to be a bug(?) though, noticed it in Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139, where there are sometimes numbers shown that are not the original size. I don't know what else ...